How can Anglican clergy be suspended, without pay, for teaching what the Anglican church states to be its theological beliefs?
I am not a member of the Anglican Community but have not failed to notice that, for a long time, British media has been showing up some terrible goings-on with some of the Church of England clergy, whose gross misconduct, over many years, has been effectively swept under the carpet by their ‘superiors’. My concern now leads to a question, based on news this year of the opposite appearing to now be done: decent clergymen who believe in upholding sound doctrine being castigated as “a potential threat to children”, simply because certain biblical teachings are taught. This issue was reported on this website:
https://freespeechunion.org/justin-welby-plainly-wrong-over-egregious-blacklisting-of-gender-critical-chaplain/
Earlier information I received from The Christian Institute indicates what is going on, behind the scenes, that has so influenced the Church of England that it is now going to have to either ditch some of their theological doctrines or ditch the new “Critical Theory” it is embracing. See http://www.the.ci/CriticalTheoryLT  and http://www.the.ci/ChallengingTruth  or watch their videos http://www.the.ci/CriticalTheoryWatch
What kind of a pass have things come to that clergy upholding the Church of England’s doctrinal stance where it now appears to clash with certain aspects of Critical Theory, are deemed a threat, and suspended from office? What are those clergy to do? What should members of the Church of England do to support decent clergy who uphold biblical doctrines in word, and by deed?

"What should members of the Church of England do to support decent clergy who uphold biblical doctrines in word, and by deed?" - Become Catholic

I understand that religious Christians may see this differently, but it appears that the pastor criticized "LBGT ideology." Since LBGT people are a group of loosely associated gender identities and sexual orientations, ascribing some type of unifying "ideology" to them as a whole does seem potentially homophobic. He also made some statements that reasonably could have been seen as telling students that they should view transgender identity as incoherent.

It seems that he also went off on a statement about "smashing heteronormativity," calling it "radical Marxist" or something of the sort. However, whatever some might think, opposing heteronormativity does not imply wanting to seize the means of production and usher in a class-free society. Nor, for that matter, is either the same as critical theory—to the extent critical theorists can even agree on what it is, and particularly what it isn't—and it is not clear to me that the Church of England has adopted critical theory as a theological position, short of their own statements on the matter.

@Obie2.0  My Q hopes to flag up how the CofE has now moved away from its biblical basis of belief (in particular respects) yet seeks to silence clergy who stick to that, instead of to some new populist beliefs that have now got a stranglehold on Western society. Should not the CofE simply drop its once essential doctrines on those matters, replacing them with new 'wokism' doctrines that clergy must swear to uphold? The Q is not about whether any clergy are right or wrong, but whether they are right to speak according to their biblical conscience.

I'd be interested in whether there is a canonical source of the Church of England's doctrine, the way there is in the Catholic Church. If not, it is a moving target and what conformed to it 50 years ago may not conform today.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica  I'm thinking in terms of clergy ordination vows, as it seems that many C of E clergy cannot, in conscience based on their ordination vows, go along with now-changed moral stances that they are expected to publicly agree with, and not to dissent from. This seem to be at odds with the vows they took many years ago. I will check with a family whose son is on the horns of this dilemma right now.

@Anne After reading it, I don't think the ordination vow (which I just read -- I hope it is the correct text) contains any however indirect language about sexual orientation issues. It does however emphasize the authority of the church superiors: "Will you reverently obey your Ordinary, and other chief Ministers, submitting yourselves to their godly judgements?" -- "I will so do, the Lord being my helper."

@Peter-ReinstateMonica  Thanks for that, Peter. I will get back to you on that.

@Anne I asked a question about official C of E doctrine, linking back here.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica  That is an excellent Q you have recently asked! But I'm asking about something else; the right of a priest in the CofE to publicly voice objection to anything deemed to be contrary to the word of God. In the link you gave about their ordination vows, I saw 3 that would justify their objections despite their 'superiors' saying they must not publicly object. This is about freedom of speech when they have not broken any ordination vow.

What are those clergy to do ?

Well, they could seek protection from a non-religious organisation, the Free Speech Union which supports people who find themselves in a place of discrimination due to their religious beliefs.
This very month, the Free Speech Union is offering membership to Anglican Clergy in the expected worsening state of orthodox clergy who wish to actually preach the gospel and uphold the word of God.

For the 12 days of Christmas, starting today, the Free Speech Union is offering discount annual membership to all Anglican Clergy – just £34.99 for an entire year. Click here to take advantage of this special offer.
Why Join the FSU?
Under Justin Welby, clergy were cancelled for believing in the Bible and using their common sense, but his successor is bound to be even more ‘progressive’. If you’re an Anglican minister who’s worried you might be targeted under the new Archbishop for saying something controversial, e.g. expressing orthodox Christian beliefs, now is the time to join the FSU.
The FSU stands for religious freedom. We believe every Anglican vicar has the right to express Christian views in their church without losing their livelihood. Preach from the Bible, and if the C of E Stasi come for you, we’ll have your back.
For just £34.99 for the whole year – more than 40% less than our standard annual membership – you can be part of a movement that values religious freedom, intellectual tolerance and individual rights.
This offer ends on January 6th, so sign up now to secure your membership.

[Circular sent out by email on 23rd December 2024]
Free Speech Union Website regarding Justin Welby

What protection does the FSU offer, exactly? "Be part of a movement" sounds a lot like "donate to us" and not a lot like "and then we'll protect you."

@DanielB You can check out the activity of the FSU online. They have supported many people in employment situations, in political situations and in government. They arrange legal counsel and legal support to push procedures through the Court which will not only benefit particular situations but which will set legal precedents for the future which will protect others. I am not a member of FSU myself and I cannot speak for them. I have only advertised this circular as it directly concerns the Anglican Communion.
